# Encapsulate/extract IP in/from UDP using libnetfilter_queue

Tags: linux, netfilter

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283043/rewriting-network-packets-on-the-fly-using-libnetfilter-queue) question libnetfilter_queue good choice for mangling packet using userspace app, but I need implement some  IP over UDP scenario.

Is this good idea to return using nfq_set_verdict new packet (UDP datagram) with encapsulated IP?